# How to set up a dev. environment for ARM board AT91SAM7-EX256 under x86 Linux?

Tags: embedded, arm, cross-compiling

I am a newbie to embedded developement, as figure shown. I have a small ARM board, [**AT91SAM7-EX256**](http://www.voti.nl/shop/catalog.html?ARM-SAM7-EX256). I have also a JTAG programmer dongle, too. I am using Linux (**Ubuntu x86_32**) on my notebook and desktop machine. I'm using [CodeSourcery Lite](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm) for cross-compiling to ARM-Linux.

1. Am I right that I can't use this Linux-target cross-compiler to make binary or hex files for the small ARM board (it comes without any operating system)? Should I use the version called [ARM EABI](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release1802) instead?
2. As I see, it's a "generic" ARM compiler. I've read some docs, and there're lot of options to specify the processor type and instruction set (thumb, etc.), there will be no problem with it. But how can I tell the compiler, how should the image (bin/hex) looks like for the specific board (startup, code/data blocks etc.)? (In assemblers, there're the *org* and *load* directives for it.)
3. What software do I need to capture some debug messages from the board on my PC? I don't want to on-board debugging, I just need some detailed run-time signal, more than just blinking leds.
4. I have an option to use MS-Windows, I can get a dedicated machine for it. Do you recommend it, is it much easier?
5. Can I use inline assembly somehow in my C code? I dunno anything about that. Can I use C++ or just C?

---

*I have also a question, which don't need to answer: are there really 4096 kind of GNU compilers and cross-compilers (from Linux_x86_32 -> Linux_x86_32, Linux_x86_32 -> Linux_ARM, OSX -> Linux_ARM, PPC_Linux -> OSX) and 16 different GNU compiler sources (as many target platforms/processors exists) around? The signs says "yes", but I can't believe it. Correct me, and show me the GNU compiler which can produce object file for any platform/processor, and the universal linker which can produce executable for any platform.*

Comment: If you want an easy to use muti host multi target cross compiler, then take a look at CodeTyphon. Among others, it can target both ARM with Linux and without any OS. http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Windows is not a "better" platform do this kind of embedded development on, it may be easier to start with since you can get a pre-built environment to work with. For example, [Yagarto](http://www.yagarto.de/) (which I would recommend).

Setting up an embedded development environment on Linux can require a considerable amount of knowledge, but it's not impossible.

To answer your questions:

1. Your Linux cross-compiler comes with libraries to build executables for a Linux environment. You have hinted that you want to build a bare-metal executable for this board. While you can do this with your compiler, it will just confuse things. I recommend building a baremetal cross-compiler. Since you're building your own baremetal executable (and thus you *are* the operating system, the ABI doesn't matter since you're generating all of the code and not interoperating with other previously built code.
2. There are several versions of the ARM instruction set (and Thumb). You need to generate code for your particular processor. If you generate the code for a newer version of the instruction set, you will likely generate code which generates a reserved instruction exception. Most prebuilt gcc cross-compiler toolchains for ARM are "multilib" and will build for a variety of architectures in both ARM and Thumb.
3. Not sure exactly what you're looking for here. This is a bare metal platform. You can use the debugger channel to send messages if you're debugging on target, or you'll need to build your own communication channel into the firmware you write (i.e. uart support).
4. See above.
5. Yes. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for details on gcc's extended inline assembly syntax. You can do this in C++ and C. You can also simply link pure assembly files.

There is no universal gcc compiler / linker. You need a uniquely built compiler for each host / target combination you use.

Finally, please take a look at [Atmel's documentation](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_docs.asp?category_id=163&family_id=605&subfamily_id=1724&tool_id=3759). They have a wealth of information on developing for this target as well as a board package with the needed linker directives and example programs. Note of course the package is for Atmel's own eval board, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://sam7stuff.blogspot.com/
```

I use either of the codesourcery lite versions.  But I have no use for the gcc library nor a C library, I just need a compiler.

In the gcc 3 days newlib was great, modify two files worth of system support (simple open, close, read, putc type stuff) and you could compile just about anything, but with gcc 4.x you cannot even go back and cross compile gcc 3.x, you have to install an old linux distro in a virtual machine.

To get the gcc library yes you probably want to use the eabi version not the version with linux gnueabi in the file names.

You might also consider llvm (if you dont need a C library, and you will still need binutils), hmm, I wonder if newlib compiles with llvm.

I prefer to avoid getting trapped in sandboxes, learn the tools and how to manipulate the linker, etc to build your binaries.